# Syntax for Data in variable A or Data in variable B or Data variable A is null and variable B is null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, null

I had a user request to be able to select data by employee ID value or Employee Name value.  In the event neither is requested pull all employees.

My first impulse was to create two variables: `@EmpID` and `@Name`

then

```
select a,b,c,d,e
where
(
    c between date1 and date 2
    and
    d > 0
)
and
(
    a in (@EmpID)
    or
    b = @Name
)
```

It works great if I supply values for `@Empid` or `@Name`.

What I can't figure out is how to get it to return everyone if `@EmpID is null` and `@Name is null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra `OR` statement to your `WHERE` clause:

```
and
    (
        (a = @EmpID)
        or
        (b = @Name)
        or
        (@EmpID IS NULL AND @Name IS NULL)
    )
```

If both `@EmpID` and `@Name` are `NULL`, then all employees will be returned.  Keep in mind that the `WHERE` clause:

```
(
    c between date1 and date 2
    and
    d > 0
)
```

will still be applied to any employees selected.

Comment: OK. Thanks - that took care of it.